# Κηφάς (Greek proper name) < κεϕαλή (head) < πέτρος (rock)?

Tags: greek, aramaic, peter, etymology, syriac

Are [Κηφάς](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%9A%CE%B7%CF%86%E1%BE%B6%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) (a Greek proper name < Aramaic כיפא‎, kēp̄ā, "rock"), [κεϕαλή](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CE%B5%CF%86%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%AE) (head), and [πέτρος](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=greek&l=%CF%80%CE%AD%CF%84%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%82#lexicon) (rock) etymologically related?

[Jn. 1:42](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=50&ch=1&l=42-#x): "Thou shalt be called [Cephas](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cephas) (Κηφάς), which is interpreted Peter (πέτρος)."
[Mt. 16:18](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=16&l=18-#x): "That thou art Peter (Πέτρος); and upon this rock (πέτρα) I will build my Church".

Comment: Why are you linking κεϕαλή to these verses? Is it in a neighbouring verse?

Comment: It must be a cognate word or related word due to similarity of root. Head is a word derived from the rock or vice versa. Head/Rock. You should ask this on linguistics SE for better answers.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "NO".  Let me be more specific.

**κεϕαλή** = head in Koine Greek

**πέτρος** = stone (pebble) in Koine Greek

**Κηφάς** = stone/rock in Aramaic

Aramaic is a Semitic language (eg, Hebrew, Moabite, Arabic, Chaldean) in a different class/category of languages from Greek.  Greek is an Indo-European language (eg, Slavic, Hittite, Germanic languages, Latin, etc) with very different vocabulary, grammar and structure from the Semitic languages.

Thus, Κηφάς is not linguistically related to the other words.

However, Κηφάς is translated by πέτρος because both carry similar (not identical) meanings in their respective languages.  Jesus exploited this (John 1:42) similar meaning and gave Simon (his Hebrew name), also known as Kephas (his Aramaic name), the Greek equivalent, Petros (his Greek name).

In Matt 16:18 we have a more subtle use of Greek word gender because we have distinction between the masculine Petros and the feminine Petra:

- In Matt 16:18 the disciple Peter is called "Petros" (masc., stone or pebble)
- In 1 Cor 10:4 it is Jesus who is called the "Petra" (fem.), "**bedrock or massive rock formation**" (BDAG)

Answer (score 2):

In the Matthew 16:18 text, Christ is speaking about a new work about to start, that of him building his *'ekklesia'* upon a certain 'rock'. That Greek word, *'ekklesia'* was long in use before being taken up in the New Testament. Lexicographers generally say it means 'an assembly duly summoned'. Jesus was speaking of a new assembly he would summon to be called out of this world, of which the apostle Peter would be but one of many members, albeit one of only 12 apostles. Now we know what would be built by Christ, the question is, *would this gathering of called-out ones be built upon Peter (*Petros* in Greek), or something or someone else?*

The Greek word for 'rock', *'petra',* is that from which the name, Peter, *'Petros',* is derived. **But derivation is not identification.** Consider:

Is snow the same thing as a snowflake? Is rain the same thing as a raindrop? They all have identical substance, while retaining a difference in form, and the words have a particular meaning in one case that is not the same in the other. They are not identical things.

Some who claim that when Jesus said, "On this rock I will build my *ekklesia*'", he meant the man, Peter, have made a misleading insertion of two other Greek texts which they imply bolsters their case. In translations with marginal readings, they put Ephesians 2:20 which says that Christians "are built upon the foundation of the apostles and prophets, ***Jesus Christ himself being the chief corner stone***" in whom all grow into a symbolic holy temple to God. Yet a foundation is not a stone, in this text. ***A foundation may be dug into stone - rock, but the foundation is not the rock into which it is sunk***. Further, Peter is not singled out for special mention; all the apostles, and all the prophets are equal here. The special mention is reserved for Christ, who is the chief corner stone of this spiritual 'building'. Talk about stumbling over Christ, 'the stone of stumbling', for the Ephesians 2 text speaks of an entirely different thing to that in Mat. 16!

Likewise in Revelation 21:14, also used by some to imply linkage to 'rock' in Mat. 16. This describes the wall of heavenly New Jerusalem having 12 foundations with the names of the 12 apostles of the Lamb inscribed on them. Now, if it had said the wall (in heaven) had one foundation with the name of the apostle Peter inscribed on it, then it could rightly be linked to Mat. 16. But the Revelation text never mentions the foundation of the city. Its walls are not the church; ***the city is the church***. The walls surround and protect the city, while remaining distinct from it. Nor are any keys mentioned. This means that the Rev.21 text has no business being linked to the Mat. 16 text.

Sticking purely to the Mat. 16 text, the Greek words about a masculine name, and something upon which Christ builds his gathered church of people, may well have the same derivation, but derivation is not the same as identification. In many places elsewhere in the New Testament, the foundation of Christ's church is shown to be the Rock - Jesus Christ. To try to build what is claimed to be Christ's church upon any human, and not solely upon Jesus Christ, is to invite a collapse, like something built on sand.

**Greek words that are related cannot be used to prove something that the Bible does not actually state**, indeed, which actually states that the rock upon which Christ builds his *'ekklesia'* is himself.